# Problema de constructor en C++. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Tags: c++, poo, constructor

Esta es la clase alumno, a partir de aqui debo usar el codigo para hacer un constructor en Posgrado.cpp.

```
#ifndef ALUMNO_H
#define ALUMNO_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class alumno{
  public:
  alumno(string,string,string,double,int);
  ~alumno();
  void ponCodigo(string);
  void ponNombre(string);
  void ponDireccion(string);
  double devCostoPeriodo() const;
  int devCantidadPeriodos() const;
  virtual void imprime() const;
  virtual double PrecioPrograma();
  private:
  string codigo;
  string nombre;
  string direccion;
  long double costoPeriodo;
  int cantidadPeriodos;
};
#endif
```

Esta es la clase Posgrado.H, aqui estan los objetos.

```
#ifndef POSGRADO_H
#define POSGRADO_H


#include "alumno.h"

class posgrado : public alumno{
  public:
  posgrado(string,string,double,int,string,float=0.0);
  ~posgrado();
  void ponTituloObtenidoPregrado(string);
  void ponPromedioPregrado(float);
  virtual void imprime() const;
  virtual double PrecioPrograma();
  private:
  string TituloObtenidoPregrado;
  float PromedioPregrado;
};
#endif
```

Aqui debo hacer un constructor, no se como hacerlo, he intentado de todo y aun no encuentro respuesta. Alguien que me pueda ayudar? Este es un pequeño ejemplo que nos dejo la profesora, pero sinceramente no se como traducirlo a Posgrado.cpp: `pregrado::pregrado(string cod, string nom, string dr,double cp, int p, string prog, int pi) : alumno(cod,nom,dr,cp,p){}`. Gracias de antemano, tengo la cabeza muy quemada pensando en esto ya dos dias seguidos jaja

```
#include "posgrado.h"

posgrado::posgrado(string to,string imp,double cp,int to,float pp = 0.0)
{
  ponTituloObtenidoPregrado(to);
  ponPromedioPregrado(pp);
}
posgrado::~posgrado(){}
void posgrado::ponTituloObtenido(string to){
  tituloObtenido = to;
}
void posgrado::ponPromedioPregrado(float pp){
  promedioPregrado = (pp < 0.0 || pp > 5.0 ? 0.0 : pp);
}
void posgrado::imprime() const{
  alumno::imprime();
  cout<<endl<<"Titulo obtenido en pregrado: "<<tituloObtenido;
  cout<<endl<<"Promedio obtenido en pregrado: "<<promedioPregado;
}
double posgrado::PrecioPrograma(){
  double precio;
  if(promedioPregrado > 4.0)
  precio = (devCostoPeriodo()* devCantidadPeriodos())*0.8
  else
  precio = devCostoPeriodo()* devCantidadPeriodos();
  return precio;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Sospecho que el constructor de `posgrado` te da un error ¿es ese el problema?

Comment: Efectivamente. No se hacer el constructor de Posgrado.cpp, ni fijándome del ejemplo que nos dió la profesora, así que lo encuentro un poco difícil porque es literalmente lo único que me falta del código, porque el resto ya todo esta terminado

Comment: @DanielVillalba, puedes revisar documentación en español de C++.  En particular, para clases y constructores aquí: https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language

A la derecha verás lo correspondiente a clases y constructores, con ejemplos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que la maestra quiere es ver si sabes implementar los constructores de las clases heredadas.. en este caso se deben de inicializar explícitamente los constructores de las clases de las cuales heredan... aquí un ejemplo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Alumno {
private:
    std::string nombre;

public:
    Alumno(std::string nombreAlumno)
        : nombre(nombreAlumno)
    { /* constructor de alumno */ }

    void saludo() {
        std::cout << "Hola, soy " << nombre << "\n";
    }

    // esto se debe de implementar a fuerzas para que compile
    virtual void despedida() = 0;
};

class Posgrado : public Alumno {
public:
    Posgrado(std::string nombreAlumnoPosgrado)
        : Alumno(nombreAlumnoPosgrado)
    { /* este constructor inicializa el nombre del un alumno de posgrado*/ }

    void despedida() override {
        std::cout << "adios mundo cruel!" << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Posgrado alumnoPosgrado("Fulano");

    alumnoPosgrado.saludo(); // metodo heredado
    alumnoPosgrado.despedida(); // implementación de un metodo virtual

    return 0;
}
```

> Salida de la terminal

```
Hola, soy Fulano
adios mundo cruel!
```

> Ejemplo con la interfaz separada de la implementación

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Alumno {
private:
    std::string nombre;

public:
    Alumno(std::string nombreAlumno);

    void saludo();

    // esto se debe de implementar a fuerzas para que compile
    virtual void despedida() = 0;
};

Alumno::Alumno(std::string nombreAlumno)
    : nombre(nombreAlumno)
{ /* constructor de alumno */ }

void Alumno::saludo() {
    std::cout << "Hola, soy " << nombre << "\n";
}

class Posgrado : public Alumno {
public:
    Posgrado(std::string nombreAlumnoPosgrado);

    void despedida() override;
};

int main() {
    Posgrado alumnoPosgrado("Fulano");

    alumnoPosgrado.saludo(); // metodo heredado
    alumnoPosgrado.despedida(); // implementacion de un metodo virtual

    return 0;
}

Posgrado::Posgrado(std::string nombreAlumnoPosgrado)
    : Alumno(nombreAlumnoPosgrado)
{ /* este constructor inicializa el nombre del un alumno de posgrado*/ }

void Posgrado::despedida() {
    std::cout << "adios mundo cruel!" << "\n";
}
```